# How to avoid RejectedExecutionException with java.net HttpClient after upgrade to Java 17?

Tags: java, java-17

I am upgrading a project from Java 11 to Java 17. This project uses `java.net.http.HttpClient` in several places which after the upgrade run into the following exception:

```
    ...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.tryCompensate(ForkJoinPool.java:1819)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.compensatedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3446)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3432)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1898)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2072)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:553)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
    ...
```

From what I understand the problem is that HttpClient uses `CompletableFuture` which calls `ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(q);` in line 1898. This uses the [static common pool of ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) (correct me if I'm wrong) and I don't have any chance to tell my application to create a separate pool for these calls (or do I?). Furthermore in Java 17 the [behavior changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69768534/why-does-java-17-throw-a-rejectedexecutionexception-when-adding-tasks-to-a-forkj) how java deals with the situation when all threads of the pool are in use - which now leads to this exception.

Is there a way around this problem? I already played around with the system parameters `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` and `...common.maximumSpares` but without the desired result.

What can I do to avoid this exception? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Have you tried to use a custom Executor and pass it to the HttpClient instead of a ForkJoinPool. This allows you to have more control over the thread pool used by the HttpClient and can potentially avoid the RejectedExecutionException :shrug:

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that I already tried that. The thing is, that this executor is not used for the `CompletableFuture` which calls directly `ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(q);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that in our case we used a `ForkJoinPool` around all this and **we had to configure its *saturate predicate***:

This all happened in our JUnit5 tests where we use a custom [ParallelExecutionConfiguration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.0/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/support/hierarchical/ParallelExecutionConfiguration.html). This executes our tests in parallel by the use of `ForkJoinPool`.

Luckily the mentioned interface provides a new method
[getSaturatePredicate()](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.9.0/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/support/hierarchical/ParallelExecutionConfiguration.html#getSaturatePredicate()) starting with JUnit 5.9.0. So all we had to do is to upgrade JUnit5 and implement this method:

```
@Override
public Predicate<? super ForkJoinPool> getSaturatePredicate() {
    return forkJoinPool -> true;
}
```