# Java 21 virtual Thread error RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker

Tags: java, virtual-threads

My code has a lot of number of network IO operations, I IO operations at a time when using a new virtual Thread, program error tip RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker.
I understand that the virtual thread should be independent of the ForkJoinPool thread number and can be created at will. Why does the problem of insufficient number of threads occur ?
this is code

```
Thread.startVirtualThread(() -> minioUtil.uploadAndDelete(originPath, targetPath, bucketName));
```

this is error

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker
    at simple.other.minio.MinioUtil.uploadAndDelete(MinioUtil.java:120)
    at simple.service.uploadFileService.UploadFileService.lambda$uploadMailToMinio$0(UploadFileService.java:54)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.tryCompensate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.compensatedBlock(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at io.minio.S3Base.uploadParts(S3Base.java:2704)
    at io.minio.S3Base.lambda$putMultipartObjectAsync$23(S3Base.java:2735)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I want the virtual thread that is doing the IO operation to be automatically suspended without occupying the ForkJoinPool's platform thread resources until the IO operation is finished

Comment: The use of virtual threads is not without pitfalls. For instance, synchronized blocks do not yield the worker threads once blocked. Are you using synchronized either on method declarations or within methods?

Comment: It looks like an addition to a vast collection of virtual threads bugs. `ForkJoinPool` is an _internal_ feature of virtual threads, it wasn't involved directly in the OP code and this kind of exception should not be exposed to the OP. Even if the OP used synchronization, like @ODDminus1 suggested, this could lead in a worst case scenario to pinning, but not to an exception or hanging.

Comment: This problem looks like `ForkJoinPool` saturate handling rather than virtual threads - see [Why does Java 17 throw a RejectedExecutionException when adding tasks to a ForkJoinPool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69768534/why-does-java-17-throw-a-rejectedexecutionexception-when-adding-tasks-to-a-forkj/69772222#69772222)